Can someone help me with a LED light fixture puzzlement?
I have been buying and using LED bulbs from the Dollar Tree for many years.
I have never had an issue with them in the past. Just the occasional burn out in my home office fixture because it stays on 14 - 16 hours a day. My living room, bedroom, hallway, bath, laundry and kitchen fixtures have not had a change in years because they aren't used very often. Of course I live alone, otherwise my electric bill would be double!
I recently picked up some Daylight bulbs that have the manufacturer's name Yamo on them because I happened to be near a Dollar Tree store. There is not one close by.
I like one soft light and one daylight bulb in my ceiling light because I find two soft light are not bright enough and two daylight are too harsh.
The manufacturer's name on the ones I have been using is Syn Top.
So here is the puzzlement.I replaced a burned out Syn Top daylight with one of these new Yamo labeled ones and it wouldn't work.
I figured I had a bad bulb so I got another of the new Yamo ones and it would not work either. Then a third, same!
Hmmm, I thought.
Bad fixture?
I took the fixture down and wired a cord to it and tested each socket.
120 volts one both.
I tested the wiring to the fixture, 120 volts.
So, I took one of the new ones that would not work and put it in my desk lamp and it worked.
I put my desk lamp bulb in the fixture and it worked.
For some reason, these new bulbs will not work in a two light fixture.
I went to the store and bought a new two light ceiling fixture on the off chance there was some sort of issued with the fixture..
Same exact result.
I put two of the older Syn Top labeled bulbs in the new fixture and they work fine.
I took the new fixture to my shop and repeated all the above tests with the exact same result.
I removed the working bulb from the fixture so that the only bulb is the new one.
It won't work when it is the only bulb in the fixture.
I tried it in two work lamps I have in the shop and it works in them.
I have tried this new Yamo labeled bulb in three different single socket lamps and it works.
I have tried this new Yamo labeled bulb in two different ceiling two socket fixtures and it will not work when another bulb is present.
I have tried this new Yamo labeled bulb in two different ceiling two socket fixtures and it will not work when it is the only bulb in the fixture.
I do not have a Yamo labeled soft light to test so I don't know if the issued is just with daylight bulbs or all Yamo bulbs.
I'm sure not driving 36 miles to buy one to test nor is it worth it to drive 36 miles to return them.
One last thing I failed to mention above.
I remember that the little 3v LEDs are polarity sensitive.
I found an old non-polarized lamp cord and wired it to the fixture. I inserted the plug in both orientations and the Yamo bulb wouldn't work but the Syn Top didn't care and worked regardless of how the plug was oriented.
So, electrical, electronical engineers out there, what the heck?

Your house wiring is alternating voltage. It alternates polarity 60 times per second. Polarity of plug does not matter.

I am very well aware of A/C and D/C current! And yes, polarity on an A/C circuit does matter in certain LED lights. I have LED overhead in my shop and one feed had the line and common reversed and the fixtures on that feed would illuminate but not shut off completely, only dim until i discovered the issue. I simply inserted that bit of information as nothing more that information to provide every known troubleshooting step I took.

Yes, the not shutting off would be due to switched neutral (instead of switched live) with enough capacitance to ground or other neutrals to keep the LEDs lit.

@Transistor Or switched live, same capacitive current.

@winny, ah, but it seemed to solve itself in this case when swapped.

Yep, exactly my findings.

Thanks all, But what about the LED bulbs in my house? That was the question posted.

Is there anything special in the ceiling lights? Series / parallel switching for dim / bright? Dimmer switch anywhere? Are they just simple parallel bulb-holders?

Simple switch. Off/On, no dimming. Simple parallel bulb holders. Most basic of two bulb lighting fixture. Note in my question that I removed the fixture and tested it on my home workbench and at my farm equipment work shop bench with the same results. In these tests the fixture was wired direct to a power cord, no switch.

Dumb thought - is there any chance the two sockets in the double-lamp fixture are wired in series?

We would have to see the fixture wiring, and voltage measurements with the bulbs in place (working and non cases). This is mostly a using-devices question, and the likely explanation is "the bulbs are terrible", but I'm still intrigued enough that I would support a reopen vote after an edit.

I have seen bulbs that are shaped so that the center connection of the Edison base is prevented from contacting the fixture center contact (the bulb shape interferes with the tubular portion of the socket).
In one case I solved it by soldering a washer onto the base of the bulb.

That was my very first thought. I took a pick and lifted the center tab so that it would contact. That had no effect so I soldered a blob on to one of the bulbs. No change. Still no illuminate. So, why does it work in three different single socket lamps but not in two different two socket fixtures? I am suspecting that there is some sort of difference in the circuitry internal to the bulb. I have taken one apart a few years ago when I saw Big Clive on YouTube working on one and I wanted to see for myself what was inside one. Tiny little circuit board.
